# How to move the video position when we drag the custom seekbar?

Tags: android, android-videoview, android-seekbar

In My Application,selecting the video from gallery and put it in videoview

```
<VideoView 
    android:id="@+id/videoview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rel_navbar"/>
```

I want to move the video position whenever i drag the customized Range seekbar and also diaplay the time with moving positions.

```
private void seekbar() 
    {
        Log.e("mnvalue is","<><."+minvalue);
        Log.e("maxvalue is","<><>"+maxvalue);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         seekBar = new RangeSeekBar<Integer>(minvalue, maxvalue,this);
         layout.addView(seekBar);
         seekBar.setOnRangeSeekBarChangeListener(new OnRangeSeekBarChangeListener<Integer>() 
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onRangeSeekBarValuesChanged(RangeSeekBar<?> bar, Integer minValue,Integer maxValue) 
                        {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Log.e("minvalue is","<><><>"+minValue);
                            Log.e("maxvalue is","<><><>"+maxValue);
                            minvalue1=minValue;
                            maxvalue1=maxValue;
                            trim=1;

                            int videoposition1=videoview.getCurrentPosition();
                            //int videoposition_1=videoposition1/1000;
                            Log.e("videopositopn is","<><>"+videoposition1);
                            videoview.seekTo(videoposition1);

                        }
                    });
    }
```

But when i drag the position the video position is not moving ?Please tell me what can I do?
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In RangeSeekbar class take two static int variables that is tempmin amd tempmax.


 public final void trackTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
                final int pointerIndex = event.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
                final float x = event.getX(pointerIndex);

                if (Thumb.MIN.equals(pressedThumb)) 
                {
                    Log.e("min value","minvalue");
                    tempmin=1;
                    tempmax=0;
                    Log.e("tempmin is","<><>"+tempmin);
                    setNormalizedMinValue(screenToNormalized(x));
                }
                else if (Thumb.MAX.equals(pressedThumb)) 
                {
                    Log.e("max value","maxvalue");
                    tempmax=1;
                    tempmin=0;
                    Log.e("tempmax ix","<><>"+tempmax);
                    setNormalizedMaxValue(screenToNormalized(x));
                }
        }

 In your Activity change the code as follows,
```

Videovirewfortrim is the videoview refrence

```
videoviewfortrim.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) 
            {
                float minvalue=videoviewfortrim.getCurrentPosition();
                final float maxvalue=videoviewfortrim.getDuration();

                 final RangeSeekBar<Float> seekbar = new RangeSeekBar<Float>(minvalue, maxvalue2,getParent());

                      layout.addView(seekbar);

                       seekbar.setOnRangeSeekBarChangeListener(new OnRangeSeekBarChangeListener<Float>() 
                     {
                            @Override
                            public void onRangeSeekBarValuesChanged(
                                    RangeSeekBar<?> bar, Float minValue,
                                    Float maxValue) 
                            {

                                  if(RangeSeekBar.tempmin==1)
                                {
                                    videoviewfortrim.seekTo((int) (minValue*1000));
                                    if(seekbar.isPressed())
                                    {
                                        videoviewfortrim.pause();
                                        imgviewplay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    }
                                }
                                else if(RangeSeekBar.tempmax==1)
                                {
                                    videoviewfortrim.seekTo((int) (maxValue*1000));
                                    if(seekbar.isPressed())
                                    {
                                        videoviewfortrim.pause();
                                        imgviewplay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    }
                                }
                           }
                     }
               }
       }
```